TexLive and MikTex produce different references using cref
Problem description
I use Texlive 2024 in a docker-image to build my PDF in a github action. On my laptop I use TexStudio with MikTex to build my PDF. TexLive and MikTex produce different outputs for the references when using \cref{}. I want to figure out why and how I can solve the issue.
I can reproduce the TexLive issue on my laptop, using the docker:
FROM texlive/texlive:latest
In both cases I'm using lualatex for building the PDF. I get the same results with pdflatex or xelatex.
Used versions:

used version of longtable:

texLive: v4.20 from 2024-4-26
MikTex: the longtable package does not appear in the list of installed packages ;-(


used version cleverref:

texlive: v021.4 from 2018-4-22
miktex: v021.4 from 2018-4-22



What I already tried

use pdflatex and xelatex. They produce the same output.
I tried different table environments:

tabalar inside a \begin{table} ... \end{table} does not have the same issue.
collected keyvaltable has the same issue
I placed the longtable into a \begin{table} ... \end{table}, this did not help.


I placed the caption and label at the end of the longtable
I placed the label inside the caption: \caption{Cherries \label{tab:recipe}}

My question
I can use some hints of how to figure out what is going on. Does anyone have an idea?
MWE
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Table referencing problem}\label{ch:this_chapter}
    When using cleverref, we get this reference to the table: \textbf{\cref{tab:recipe}}. 

    When using a good-old ref: \textbf{table~\ref{tab:recipe}}. 

    This should show "\textbf{table 1.1}" both times.    
    
    \let\tableHeader\outer\renewcommand{\tableHeader}{\textbf{amount} & \textbf{ingeredient} & \textbf{step}\\}
    \let\numcols\outer\renewcommand{\numcols}{3}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{longtable}{c c c}
            \caption{Cherries} \label{tab:recipe}\\
            \tableHeader
            \endfirsthead
    
            \multicolumn{\numcols}{c}{{\textbf{\tablename\ \thetable{}:} \textit{\ldots continued from previous page}}} \\
            \tableHeader
            \endhead
        
            \multicolumn{\numcols}{r}{{\textit{\ldots continued on next page}}}
            \endfoot
        
            \endlastfoot
    
            150g & Ice cream & put into bowl \\
            50g  & cherries & heat up and add to bowl
            \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
\end{document}


TexLive output

MikTex output


Compare both .log files. You might have different versions for hyperref, firstaid, the latex kernel etc.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I expect you are right. The MikTex environment uses hyperref v7.00v, the texlive environment a hyperref v7.01i. There seem to be some issues with cleverref. I'm now using texlive version 2023 and this seems to be working well. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

As an alternative, you could have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/zref-clever

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for the suggestion. Is this package in principle more robust, or will I encounter other (type of) problems. Can you say something (in general) about pros and cons of zref VS cleverref? Is could not find such comperison.

I guess in the current state, any package is more robust than cleveref. The problem with cleveref is that at the time it was written, it had to heavily patch internal hyperref macros because the modification cleveref needed weren't possible otherwise. In the mean time, a lot of work has happened in hyperref, e.g. to add interfaces to make such modifications easier to do, but cleveref would need to adapt to the new code to stay compatible.

The maintainers of hyperref and the latex kernel jump through a lot of hoops to avoid completely breaking cleveref and add first aid patches where they can, but ultimately cleveref needs an update.
